# dbGetQuery in R truncates really long the SQL query (of length 10564 characters)

Tags: sql, r, db2, r-dbi

I have been trying to execute a really long SQL query and get the result into a data frame in R. But the following line throws an error and displays partial query in the console (truncates it)

```
my_dataframe <- dbGetQuery(conn, my_large_query)
```

The length of the query is 10564 characters where I use a lot of CTEs. 
I have removed the string truncation via options menu in R studio but I wonder if there a character limitation in the `dbGetQuery` function in R?

Any suggestions?

- RDMBS: DB2 (on IBM AS400),
- R Package: DBI (library - RJDBC)

Comment: What you are asking may be dependent on several factors, including the database to which you are connecting and the package being used to connect. Perhaps you could include some more information. (Having said that, a query that long is ... difficult to fathom. Perhaps this might benefit from reducing the query, using stored procedures, using views, using parameterized queries, etc.)

Comment: Can we see part of your attempted query? You might be redundantly repeating lines and can be optimized with a DRY-er solution.

Comment: It was an issue with the query (I was hitting a CTE which was coincidentally an 'actual' table in the database). Thank you for the response

Answer (score 3):

You mentioned changing the 'string truncation', but how about `warning.length`?

```
options("warning.length"={integer})
```

I'd also suggest that you test the query out first in whatever GUI is available for your database. When you verify there's no problem with the query, then run it in R.

When dbGetQuery (assuming the DBI package) throws an sql/database error, the actual content of the error won't be shown until **after the full text** of the query. In other words, if the query text is being truncated in the R error output, the database error code/text coming will not be visible at all. The issue may be something extremely simple like an unmatched bracket or a missing comma.

Please note whether the error message starts with `Error in dbGetQuery` (R issue) or `Error in .verify.JDBC.result` (database issue).

Comment: Executed it on a GUI (db2), the syntax is good. The options("warning.length") was default (i.e. 1000), I set it to 8170 and the truncated string is not displayed anymore but my session crashes abruptly

Comment: It was a database issue "Error in .verify.JDBC.result". Updated the SQL syntax - I was reading data from a bad table (which was coincidentally a valid table in the db) Thanks for the response :) Appreciate the help.